# Prove that $\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}+\frac{c}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{d}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\leq\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, nested-radicals

> For any reals $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ prove that:
> $$\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}+\frac{c}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{d}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\leq\frac{3}{2}$$

C-S in the IMO 2001 stile does not help here:
\begin{align}
&\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}+\frac{c}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{d}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2} \\
\leq&\sqrt{4\left(\tfrac{a^2}{(1+a^2)^2}+\tfrac{b^2}{(1+a^2+b^2)^2}+\tfrac{c^2}{(1+a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}+\tfrac{d^2}{(1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2}\right)}\\
\leq&2\sqrt{\tfrac{a^2}{1+a^2}+\tfrac{b^2}{(1+a^2)(1+a^2+b^2)}+\tfrac{c^2}{(1+a^2+b^2)(1+a^2+b^2+c^2)}+\tfrac{d^2}{(1+a^2+b^2+c^2)(1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)}} \\
=&2\sqrt{1-\tfrac1{1+a^2}+\tfrac1{1+a^2}-\tfrac1{1+a^2+b^2}+\tfrac1{1+a^2+b^2}-\tfrac1{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}+\tfrac1{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}-\tfrac1{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}} \\
<&2
\end{align}
We can assume that our variables are non-negative, of course.

For two variables we can get a best estimation here:
$$\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}\leq\sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}\approx0.88...$$
There is also the following Ji Chen's estimation:
$$\frac{x_1}{1+x_1^2}+\frac{x_2}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}+\dotsb+\frac{x_n}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2+\dotsb+x_n^2}<\sqrt{n}-\dfrac{\ln{n}}{2\sqrt{n}},$$
but it does not help.

Thank you!

Comment: Somebody in the link also conjectured $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{1+\sum_{m=1}^k x_k^2} \le \sqrt n - \frac{\ln n}{2\sqrt n}$$ Link: https://tieba.baidu.com/p/778327306 . (I used translator to translate $\ddot\smile$)

Comment: @VIVID I knew about this estimation. Thank you! I added.

Comment: Two variables case is a quadratic function of $b$ =))

Comment: How did you prove $$\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}\leq\sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}\approx0.88...$$?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h134716p761852), we even have $$\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}+\frac{c}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{d}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\leq 1.4704\ldots$$ Yet the case in which equality holds does not look promising...

Comment: @Dr. Mathva Thank you for your link. It's very interesting!

Comment: Denote LHS by $f(a,b,c,d)$. The system of equations of stationary points has closed form solutions. The maximum is expressed in closed form (the minimal polynomial of this value is the same as Ji Chen's). (With the help of Maple)

Comment: @River Li Yes, I see. Maybe there is something by hand...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Yes, there is something by hand.

Comment: @River Li  If so, show it. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I will post it later.

Answer (score 2):

A proof for $n=2$.

We need to prove that:
$$\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}\leq\sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}.$$
Since $x\leq|x|$ and for $ab=0$ it's obvious,  it's enough to prove this inequality for positive variables.

Now, by AM-GM
$$\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1+a^2}{b}+b}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$ and it's enough to prove that $f(a)\leq\sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}},$ where
$$f(a)=\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+a^2}}=\frac{2a+\sqrt{1+a^2}}{2(1+a^2)}.$$
Now, $$f'(a)=\tfrac{\left(2+\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right)(1+a^2)-\left(2a+\sqrt{1+a^2}\right)\cdot2a}{2(1+a^2)^2}=\tfrac{2-2a^2-a\sqrt{1+a^2}}{2(1+a^2)^2}.$$
Now, $f'(a)=0$ gives $$2(1-a^2)=a\sqrt{1+a^2}$$ and we see that should be $1-a^2>0$.

Thus, $$4(1-2a^2+a^4)=a^2+a^4$$ or
$$3a^4-9a^2+4=0$$ or
$$a^2=\frac{9-\sqrt{33}}{6}$$ or
$$a=\sqrt{\frac{9-\sqrt{33}}{6}}.$$
Now, easy to see that for this value $f$ gets a maximal value and
$$f\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{9-\sqrt{33}}{6}}\right)=\tfrac{2\sqrt{\tfrac{9-\sqrt{33}}{6}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{9-\sqrt{33}}{6}}}{2\left(1+\tfrac{9-\sqrt{33}}{6}\right)}=\tfrac{2\sqrt{9-\sqrt{33}}+\sqrt{15-\sqrt{33}}}{\sqrt2(5\sqrt3-\sqrt{11})}=\sqrt{\tfrac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}.$$
The last equality it's nice.

We can get a proof by the following Carl Schildkraut's beautiful idea:

[Why $\sqrt{23-\sqrt{17}}-2\sqrt{7-\sqrt{17}}=\sqrt{71-17\sqrt{17}}$ is true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656053)

Comment: @Dr. Mathva I posted a proof.

Answer (score 1):

First, we give some auxiliary results (Facts 1 through 3). The proofs are easy and thus omitted.

*Fact 1*: Let $a, b$ be reals. Then $\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2}\le \sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}$.

*Fact 2*: Let $\gamma$ be real. Then $\frac{\gamma}{1 + \gamma^2} + \sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\gamma^2}} < \frac{6}{5}$.

*Fact 3*: Let $a$ be real. Then $\frac{a}{1+a^2} + \frac{6}{5}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}} < \frac{3}{2}$.

$\phantom{2}$

Now, let $\alpha = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 1}}$ and $\beta = \frac{d}{ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 1}}$.
We have
\begin{align}
&\frac{c}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{d}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2} \\ 
=\ & \frac{\alpha \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 1} }{1+a^2+b^2+\alpha^2(a^2 + b^2 + 1)}\\
&\quad + \frac{\beta \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 1}}{1+a^2+b^2+\alpha^2(a^2 + b^2 + 1) +\beta^2(a^2 + b^2 + 1)}\\
=\ & \left(\frac{\alpha}{1 + \alpha^2} + \frac{\beta}{1 + \alpha^2 + \beta^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}}\\
\le\ & \sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}}
\end{align}
where we have used Fact 1.

Let $\gamma = \frac{b}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$. We have
\begin{align}
&\frac{a}{1+a^2} + \frac{b}{1+a^2+b^2} + \sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}}\\
=\ & \frac{a}{1+a^2} + \frac{\gamma \sqrt{1+a^2}}{1+a^2+\gamma^2(1+a^2)} + \sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+\gamma^2(1+a^2)+1}}\\
=\ & \frac{a}{1+a^2} + \left(\frac{\gamma}{1 + \gamma^2} + \sqrt{\frac{207+33\sqrt{33}}{512}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\gamma^2}}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\\
<\ & \frac{a}{1+a^2} + \frac{6}{5}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\\
<\ & \frac{3}{2}
\end{align}
where we have used Facts 2 and 3.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you! I think the second not so easy to prove by hand. Even if we'll change the radical on $0.89$, we'll obtain a wrong inequality. But your idea is very nice!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How about using substitution $r = \frac{2u}{1-u^2}$ for $0\le u < 1$. Also, replace the radical with $\frac{15}{17}$.